# Is it possible to assign more then one user to a backlog item in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to assign more then one user to a backlog item in TFS?

The main reason for this would be to track discussion board inside a backlog item. For example if user1 is assigned to a backlog item and wants to discuss it with user2, the user2 would never know that he is asked to be involved in this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of TFS, you can use `@` to mention a user, which will notify them. This is a feature in VSTS and TFS 2015 Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a group or a team, detail ways to achieve this, please refer the link below:

> In TFS 2012 we have added the Team artifact to the product. Out of the
>   box a team is tied to an area path. By assigning a work item to a
>   specific area path you basically assign it to a team.  If you use the
>   area path for something else today, you can also use another string
>   field in the work item that specifies the team
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn144940.aspx)
>
> In case you cannot use TFS 2012 or later, you can also add groups to
>   the Assigned To dropdown as shown in this blog post
>   [http://blogs.infosupport.com/how-to-assign-a-work-item-to-a-group-and-actually-have-it-show-a-list-of-values/]
>
> Ewald Hofman TFS Program Manager
>
> *Source Link from UserVoice:* https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5221575-visual-studio-online-allow-tasks-work-items-bugs

Comment: it seems this is not possible with team foundation services.

Comment: Is that available for VSTS?

Comment: @SeanStayn No, you could use the `@` symbo as Daniel suggested above.